# What are those little rods that stick out of a planes fuselage?

Tags: aircraft-design

I noticed quite a few of them around the nose and cockpit area of a plane when I was at the airport and wondered what they were for, could someone please help.
THERE'S A PHOTO BELOW.

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking you are most likely looking at the [Pitot tubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitot_tube)

[image]

Some angle of [attack indicators also look quite similar](https://www.flyingmag.com/how-it-works-angle-attack-indicator) and in the case of some of the A380 the Pitot tubes and angle of attack indicator are combined into one unit.